# Insert new item at top of list view when ListCollectionView.CustomSort set

Tags: wpf, sorting

I have a list view with custom sorter (set by ListCollectionView.CustomSort property), however I would like to insert new items at the top of list view. How can I suppress CustomSort?

I have an idea to tune my sort logic, so newly added item will be the first one, however this solution stinks a little bit.

Comment: Your idea of changing the sorting logic to give priority to the new items is a solution I'm using right now in another project, so I'm curious to see if people have any better ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why suppress `CustomSort`? Adapt it for your needs:

- You could give all new items an extreme value for the property used in `IComparer` object for sorting, e.G. `int.MaxValue` or `string.Empty`.
- Or create an additional property IsNew and include it into comparing process.

  ```
  class MyClass
  {
      public bool IsNew { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  class MyComparer : IComparer<MyClass>
  {
      public int Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y)
      {
          if (x.IsNew ^ y.IsNew)
          {
              return x.IsNew ? -1 : 1;
          }
          else
          {
              return StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I've created new IComperer which favors newly created items (it takes object's reference into account instead of IsNew) which I use during insertion. In your example you assume that object x is always newly created one.